# Viewing all of my open tasks in Jira

Tags: jira, task-management

On Jira's homepage, it displays all tasks assigned to me, including tasks that are "closed", "obsolete", or "won't fix". I tried searching for tasks and filtering by status, but it doesn't display all of the open tasks assigned to me.

Here's my search query:

[image]

I have a task assigned to me with the status "todo", but it isn't showing up in this search.

How can I displayed a list of all tasks assigned to me, except tasks with status "closed", "done", "obsolete", or "won't fix"?

Comment: Is the status "todo" or "To Do"? Because I think JIRA is picky about the spaces, and sometimes if a workflow is set up clumsily you can have different names for the same intended status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build your own query, excluding issues which have a certain status. Click the advanced button on the right to use JQL.

[image]

Your query would like something like:

`assignee = currentUser() and (status not in (Closed, Done, Obsolete))`

or

`assignee = currentUser() and resolved is EMPTY`

---

Learn to use JQL:

> JQL stands for JIRA Query Language (not to be confused with Java Query
>   Language). It’s the most flexible way to search for issues in JIRA and
>   is for everyone
>
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql

Comment: Just an addition: you may want to consider "assignee = currentUser() and resolved is EMPTY" instead; this is more robust in the face of changing status workflows.

Comment: @Sarov Yeah, much better I think. Added it to the answer :)